# Vector Question.... Stupid vector question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a non-zero vector $\textbf u$ with terminal point $Q(-3,2,0)$. such that $\textbf u$ has the same direction as $\textbf v =$$ (3,1,-2)$

Since vectors are defined by their components and not their location. I have said that $ OB - OA = (3,1,-2)$ where OB is the position vector that has terminal point at $(-3,2,0)$ so;

$-OA = (3,1,-2) - (-3,2,0)$

$OA = (-6,1,2)$

and now i am lost, i remember answering questions like this last week. i've just lost the technique.

Comment: Vectors have direction and length but no "terminal" and "starting" point.

Comment: @Lotus: Vectors have initial and terminal points.

Comment: I mean that the given vector V is the solution and you only have to put it in the initial point that you calculated

Comment: Are looking for the initial point?

Comment: Im looking for a vector that has the same direction as (3,1,-2). but has terminal point at (-3,2,0)

Comment: I suppose you have to draw it. Anyway, the solution is the vector v, starting at the point you calculated

Comment: but OQ - OA gives v? im sorry if i am talking rubbish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that if we have two points of a vector, the initial point $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and the terminal point $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ then $\vec{AB}=(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2,b_3-a_3)$.

We know the coordinates of the terminal point. So, $\vec{u}=(-3-a,-2-b,0-c)$. Now you can choose $a,b,c$ such that you can make $\vec{u}$ have the same direction of $\vec{v}$ by choosing $a,b,c$ in such a way that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are scalar multiples of each other.

Here's one possible answer.

Letting $a=-9, b=-4, c=4$ gives us that $\vec{u}=(6,2,-4)$, which we note has the same direction of $\vec{v}$ because they are scalar multiples of each other. In particular $2\vec{v}=\vec{u}$.

Of course you can choose other $a,b,c $ in order to make the two vectors any scalar multiple of each other, i.e, as long as $\vec{u}=\alpha\vec{v}$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.